# MySQL Query Help - Show only available Cities

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've `Cities`, `Countries` and `Customers` tables in MySQL.

```
Cities: city_id, city_name, ...
Counties: county_id, city_id, county_name, ...
Customers: cus_id, city_id, county_id, ...
```

Instead of listing all cities (and counties under cities) in a `Country` - I just want to list just `Cities` and counties which `Customers` are signed up from.

Is there any MySQL experts here to help me? Thank you.
Regards.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should post your example code including the SQL queries you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table `Customers` isn't normalized properly. You shouldn't have column `city_id` in this table because `county_id => city_id` (given the `county_id` you can find `city_id`).

I am not sure that I have understood you correctly (if not please explain better providing sample data) but for what you want i think that you can use the following query:

```
SELECT aa.city_name, bb.county_name
FROM Cities AS aa
INNER JOIN Counties AS bb
ON aa.city_id = bb.city_id
INNER JOIN Customers AS cc
ON bb.county_id = cc.county_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select UNIQUE city_id from Customers
JOIN Cities 
ON Customers.city_id=Cities.city_id;
```

I am paraphrasing there, but I hope to demonstrate my point.